# Why are <e> inside if and cond designed to be handled differently in Scheme?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, scheme, sicp

```
(if <predicate> <consequent> <alternative>)

(cond (<p1> <e1>)
  (<p2> <e2>)
   ..........
  (<pn> <en>))
```

> *A minor difference between `if` and `cond` is that the `cond`'s expression part of each*
> *`cond` clause may be a sequence of expressions.* -- SICP

I wonder why the designers of the scheme language made the expression for if and cond different.

What's the purpose of that design?

Answer (score 1):

In a language like Scheme which is not purely functional, it is often useful to allow a sequence of expressions where there is room for it in the syntax: for instance in the body of a procedure and so on.  So for instance a purely functional Lisp might have a syntax for functions which was

```
(λ (<arg> ...)
  <expression>)
```

But Scheme allows

```
(λ (<arg> ...)
  <expression-1>
  <expression-2>
  ...)
```

Where the values of all but the last expression are ignored: they just happen for side-effect.  And since there is room for this in the syntax, Scheme allows it.

However there is simply no room in the syntax of `if` for this to be the case (see below).

It would be possible to design multiway conditional expression where there was *also* no room in the syntax for it, which might look like:

```
(kond
 a 1
 b 2
 c 3
 else 4)
```

for instance (here `else` is magic to `kond`: I can't remember if SICP's Scheme has that).

But if you consider what `cond`'s syntax actually is:

```
(cond
 (a 1)
 (b 2)
 (c 3)
 (else 4))
```

Then there *is* obviously now room in the syntax to write a sequence of expressions in the result position of each clause.  And Scheme does therefore allow that because there simply is no reason not to do so.  So instead of

```
(cond
 (<t> <e>)
 ...)
```

You can write

```
(cond
 (<t> <e1> <e2> ...)
 ...)
```

For instance:

```
(cond
 (world-has-ended
  (displayln "The world has ended: rain of fire imminent")
  (rain-fire-from-sky 'yes-really))
 ...)
```

In fact, Scheme has an operator, `begin` whose whole purpose is to allow a sequence of expressions where only one is allowed.  So for instance if you want to have a sequence of expressions where there would naturally only be one, you can use `begin`:

```
(if world-has-ended
    (begin
      (displayln "The world has ended: rain of fire imminent")
      (rain-fire-from-sky 'yes-really))
    (begin
      (displayln "World has not yet ended, sorry for the frogs")
      (rain-frogs-from-sky)))
```

You can then think of `cond` as defined in terms of `if` and `begin`:

```
(cond
 (world-has-ended
  (displayln "The world has ended: rain of fire imminent")
  (rain-fire-from-sky 'also-rocks))
 (world-has-nearly-ended
  (displayln "The world has nearly ended")
  (rain-frogs-from-sky 'also-some-fire)))
```

is the same as

```
(if world-has-ended
  (begin
    (displayln "The world has ended: rain of fire imminent")
    (rain-fire-from-sky 'also-rocks))
  (if world-has-nearly-ended
      (begin
        (displayln "The world has nearly ended")
        (rain-frogs-from-sky 'also-some-fire))
      #f))
```

As to why the syntax of `cond` was designed so there is room for multiple expressions: that's a question for history.  Two things I think help to explain it:

1. A syntax like `(cond <t1> <e1> <t2> <e2> ...)` is a pain to read since you need to count the number of forms in the body, while `(cond (<t1> ...) (<t2> ...) ...)` is much easier.
2. In the early days of Lisp people who had exposure only to FORTRAN and assembler (because that's pretty much all there was) tended to write programs which were, well, like programs in FORTRAN, and had a lot of imperative operations, side-effects, sequencing and so on.  And the syntax of `cond` allows for that.

Comment: very nice answer that made me chuckle a lot, thanks for that. :) the point about (im)purity was illuminating. the missing `cond` clause though is not replaced with `#f`, I don't think. I tried `(cond (#f))` in drracket, and there was no value shown at all.

Comment: @WillNess: I think you're right: there are lots of edge cases I missed (like `(cond (3))`).  R7RS (and R5RS) both say 'is unspecified' and I think Racket returns its magic 'void' object in that case.  I also think that all this means that `(cond (else))` is illegal I think, which I didn't know.

Comment: Regarding the history ("...early days of Lisp"), Lisp 1.5 limited `COND` to a single expression after each predicate (the S-expression version of the M-expression `[p1->e1; p2->e2; ...]`), and didn't have `IF`. Maclisp had `cond` as now defined, and Scheme "R0RS" copied that; Maclisp's `if` was a macro which allowed a single consequent but a sequence of alternatives (!)

Comment: Of course, there *is* room for extra expressions in `if`, if you're willing to accept asymmetry. elisp, for example, allows multiple expressions in the else clause: `(if <p> <t> <e1> <e2...>)`.

Comment: @mnemenaut Interesting that Lisp 1.5 had single-form `cond`: I'd assumed it had multiple forms.  Standard Lisp also has this (I forget where it branched, but pretty early) so my assumption was clearly bogus.  Interlisp had implicit progn by 1974.

Comment: @amalloy: yes, Maclisp had this which I assume is where elisp got it from.  The Lisp I use mostly (LW) has *indentation rules* for it, but it's CL so it has the CL semantics.  In the answer I just tacitly assumed that the asymmetry was so ugly I didn't want to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow any number of expressions in `if`, how do you tell when the true ones end and the false ones begin?¹ With `cond`, each case is a list where the first element is the test expression and the rest of the list gets evaluated when true. There's no ambiguity.

---

1: With `begin`:

```lisp
(if <test>
  (begin <true  exprs> ...)
  (begin <false exprs> ...))
```

`cond` will typically be a macro that expands to

```lisp
(if <p1>
  (begin <e1>)
  (if <p2>
    (begin <e2>)
    ...))
```

Answer (score 0):

**`cond` has implicit `begin` in Scheme due to accidental design in the parent language of the 60s called LISP!**

If is not the designers of Scheme that designed `cond` or `if`. `cond` is the original conditional of McCarhty's paper and his `eval` does not support more than one consequent expression. Basically if you were to write more than one consequence it would just do the first. `if` did not exist in that paper and it didn't exist in Fortran at the time since it had [arithmetic if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_IF).

Wrapping each term in a parenthesis is what opens up for the newer versions of lisp to actually allow for more than one consequent with the last one being the tail expression. Imagine he didn't do that but suggested this instead:

```
; a and c are predicates
(cond a b
      c d
      t e)
```

The problem with this is that it is only my formatting that helps determining what is what. If I were to write it in one line it would be almost impossible to read this simple short code:

```
(cond a b c d t e)
```

Adding parens was a way to group the things that belongs together together. When `if` came later it did not support more than two branching in the same form and when lisp got imperative and they introduced `progn` `cond` had implicit due to accidental design while `if` needed a `progn` form so it kept only 3 operands.

You might be interested in [The roots of lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/rootsoflisp.html)

Btw. My flat `cond` example is very similar to the implementation of `if` in Paul Graham's lisp language Arc:

```
(if p1 c1
    p2 c2
    c3)
```